# Play Framework 2.3 / sbt / Ivy exception

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, ivy

A Play 2.3 project, which has previously worked well is suddenly afflicted with a major problem. I run the program from the activator console with *~run* which works fine until I do a code change. When sbt tries to recompile I get this exception:

```
play.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String]
    at play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:51) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.addAllVariables(IvySettings.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.addAllVariables(IvySettings.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.addSystemProperties(IvySettings.java:303) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.<init>(IvySettings.java:298) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.<init>(IvySettings.java:218) ~[na:na]
```

Edit: the error does not occur on the first saved code change, but every save after that.

As the error occurs in Ivy I have tried undoing the only recent change I have to dependencies, but that makes no difference.

I checked out fresh code from version control in case there was some corruption, but that didn't help either.

Edit: deleting ~/.ivy2 didn't help either, except that I found out that I had an outdated sbt plugin which I chose a new version for.

What is going on here and what can I do about it? The problem has a major impact on productivity as I have to restart Play for each time I have saved a code change.

Edit: I can stop the problem by commenting out a few lines of code, which makes no sense at all.

```
    String mailServiceClass = Configuration.root().getString("kulturnav.mailService");
    try {
        mailService = (MailService) Class.forName(mailServiceClass).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot instantiate mail service", e);
    }
    ServiceUtils.setMailService(mailService);
```

Comment: Weird. Which sbt version are you using? Does the `clean` command helps?

Comment: I started with sbt 0.13.9, then updated to 0.13.11 to see if that helped, which it didn't. I have tried clean, deleted target/*, project/target/* and project/project/target/* but that has no effect either.